# Using the gmail python API how can I get the most recent email that does not have a label "read"

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

```
results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', labelIds=['Label_8507504117657095973'], maxResults=1).execute()
```

this snippet gets the most recent email that has the arbitrary label "read". How can I adapt it get the most recent email that does **not** have this label?

```
results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', labelIds!=['Label_8507504117657095973'], maxResults=1).execute()
```

replacing `=` with `!=` doesn't work for some reason returning the error:

```
results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', labelIds!=['Label_8507504117657095973''], maxResults=1).execute() SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Rather than using the `labelIds` parameter, you can use a Gmail search operator to do your query.*

#### More Information:

As per the documentation on [Gmail search operators](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190):

> You can use words or symbols called search operators to filter your Gmail search results. You can also combine operators to filter your results even more.
>
> | What you can search by | Search operator & example |
> | --- | --- |
> | Messages that have a certain label | `label:` |
> |  | Example: `label:friends` |

So, rather than using the label ID `Label_8507504117657095973` in the `labelIds` parameter, instead you can use the above search term in the `q` parameter to remove results that *don't* have the label:

```py
labelName = "yourLabelName"
results = service.users()
                 .messages()
                 .list(userId='me', q="-label:"+labelName, maxResults=1)
                 .execute()
```

This will return a single result without the given label:

```
{
  "messages": [
    {
      "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "threadId": "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
    }
  ],
  "nextPageToken": "1309905752354234521",
  "resultSizeEstimate": 1
}
```

#### References:

- [Search operators you can use with Gmail - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190)
- [Method: users.messages.list | Gmail API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list)

Comment: that once decoded just prints "maxResults=1" multiple times instead of the email.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, can you please explain?

Comment: it prints this:

```b'maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1maxResults=1``` but longer

Comment: Hmm, I don't know why you would be getting this as a result. Could you edit your question to include your full call and print lines?

Comment: @TheTroupeMaster can you explain what the issue was for other users in the future who may run into the same problem?

Comment: I just mistyped the label name “reaf” instead of “read” once I noticed that it was fine for me